# a negative unsigned int?

Tags: unsigned, truetype

I'm trying to wrap my head around the truetype specification. On [this page](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6cmap.html), in the section *'cmap' format 4*, the parameter *idDelta* is listed as an unsigned 16-bits integer (UInt16). Yet, further down, a few examples are given, and here idDelta is given the values -9, -18, -27 and 1. How is this possible?

Comment: I was working in python and the tag was still there from a previous question. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition and use of `idDelta` on that page is not consistent. In the `struct subheader` it is defined as an `int16`, while a little earlier the same subheader is listed as `UInt16*4`.

It's probably a bug in the spec.

If you look at actual implementations, [like this one from perl Tk](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SREZIC/Tk-804.032/pTk/mTk/win/tkWinFont.c), you'll see that idDelta is usually given as signed:

```
typedef struct SUBHEADER {
    USHORT firstCode;       /* First valid low byte for subHeader. */
    USHORT entryCount;      /* Number valid low bytes for subHeader. */
    SHORT idDelta;      /* Constant adder to get base glyph index. */
    USHORT idRangeOffset;   /* Byte offset from here to appropriate
                 * glyphIndexArray. */
} SUBHEADER;
```

Or see the implementation from [libpdfxx](https://gitorious.org/libpdfxx/libpdfxx/source/bc52dc790cf114d47e760e46702a9493df0c7323%3alibpdfdoc/src/font/sfnt/tt_cmap.c):

```
struct SubHeader
{
USHORT firstCode;
USHORT entryCount;
SHORT idDelta;
USHORT idRangeOffset;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I agree it must be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug in the spec. The reason they show negative numbers in the `idDelta` row for the examples is that `All idDelta[i] arithmetic is modulo 65536.` (quoted from the section just above). Here's how that works.

The formula to get the glyph index is

`glyphIndex = idDelta[i] + c`

where `c` is the character code. Since this expression must be modulo 65536, that's equivalent to the following expression if you were using integers larger than 2 bytes :

`glyphIndex = (idDelta[i] + c) % 65536`

`idDelta` is a u16, so let's say it had the max value 65535 (`0xFFFF`), then `glyphIndex` would be equal to `c - 1` since:

`0xFFFF + 2 = 0x10001` 
`0x10001 % 0x10000 = 1`

You can think of this as a 16 integer wrapping around to 0 when an overflow occurs.

Now remember that a modulo is repeated division, keeping the remainder. Well in this case, since `idDelta` is only 16 bits, the max amount of divisions a modulo will need to do is 1, since the max value you can get from adding two 16 bit integers is `0x1FFFE` , which is smaller than `0x100000`. That means that a shortcut is to subtract 65536 (`0x10000`) instead of performing the modulo.

`glyphIndex = (idDelta[i] - 0x10000) + c`

And this is what the example shows as the values in the table. Here's an actual example from a .ttf file I've decoded :[image]

I want the index for the character code 97 (lowercase 'a').

1. 97 is greater than 32 and smaller than 126, so we use index 2 of the mappings.
2. `idDelta[2] == 65507`
3. `glyphIndex = (65507 + 97) % 65536 === 68` which is the same as `(65507 - 65536) + 97 === 68`